# Making sure that an itemview is only saved once (Kotlin)(Android)(Room)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am unable to find a way to only save an Article only once, if a user were to save an article multiple times duplicates will appear, I need the saving process to only occur once.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIt7X.png)

//Note that the `save` button in the image above doesn't work on purpose, I am removing it in the future.

The image above is for reference.

**NewsDetailActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //Reference to an instance of the itemview in the recyclerview
   article = intent.getParcelableExtra("wholeArticle")
}



override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
   when(item.itemId){
      R.id.save_news -> {
          article?.let { viewModel.saveArticle(it) }}
}
```

To keep things short, could someone advice or give me some resources to read, I can't seem to find any good ones thanks!

**What I have tried**

I have tried playing around with different logics and concepts, read through a couple of Articles and tried to reverse engineer other people's project, can't seem to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Insert#onConflict()), you will get an official Android Page where they have mentioned the purpose of **onConflict** in case of insertion.

In your Dao Class,

```
@Dao
interface ArticleDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertSongs(varargs songs: Song)
}
```

However, there are other strategies too. ([find_out](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy.Companion)) e.g. IGNORE, ABORT, FAIL, NONE, REPLACE, ROLLBACK

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQLite with room you can specify the stragegy in case of duplicate item when defining the Insert operation in the DAO.
Something like this:

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertNews(newsDB: NewsDB)
```

This way you will prevent from saving multiple rows with the same entity.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way is to utilise a field or combination of fields that uniquely identifies an article.

- Perhaps the link to the article, perhaps the date time of the article.

You then make the column or columns used to store those fields **`UNIQUE`** and then when using the **`@Insert`** specify that the `onConflict` parameter handle the conflict (rule being broken).

This would typically be using onConflict= `OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE`, in which case the rule being broken is `IGNORE`d. Although an onConflictStrategy.REPLACE can have a similar effect albeit it less efficient as rather than just ignoring the conflict the existing row is deleted and then inserted again.

The simplest, but not necessarily the most efficient, way to specify a UNIQUE column is to make that column the PRIMARY KEY which is implicitly UNQIUE.

- There can only be 1 PRIMARY KEY per table.
- The most efficient primary key is one that is an integer type, as this aliases the sqlite's **rowid** which can be accessed/handled faster than other types.

If not using the PRIMARY KEY then you can use the **`indicies`** parameter of the **`@Entity`** annotation specify and index or indexes and specify that the index should be UNIQUE.

---

### **Demo**

Consider the following 3 examples of basically the same data class (but different according to how the UNIQUEness is defined):-

**Implicitly UNIQUE via PRIMARY KEY on the title column/field**

```
@Entity
data class ArticleTitleUniqueByPrimaryKey(
    @PrimaryKey
    var title: String,
    var link: String,
    var publishDateTime: Long
)
```

**Explicitly UNIQUE via a single column/field (the link column)**

```
@Entity(
    /* Make the Link column UNIQUE */
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["link"], unique = true)
    ]
)
data class ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkColumn(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long?=null, /* will be an alias of the rowid */
    var title: String,
    var link: String,
    var publishDateTime: Long
)
```

**Explicitly UNIQUE via a composite (multiple columns/fields) INDEX (link and title)**

```
@Entity(
    /* Make a the combination of the title and link columns unique (a composite index) */
    indices = [
        Index(
            value = ["title","link"], unique = true
        )
    ]
)
data class ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkAndTitleColumn(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long?=null, /* will be an alias of the rowid */
    var title: String,
    var link: String,
    var publishDateTime: Long
)
```

**An `@Dao` annotated interface with the IGNORE conflict strategy for all three data classes** :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs{
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(articleTitleUniqueByPrimaryKey: ArticleTitleUniqueByPrimaryKey): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(articleTitleUniqueByLinkColumn: ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkColumn): Long
    @Insert( onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(articleTitleUniqueByLinkAndTitleColumn: ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkAndTitleColumn): Long
}
```

**An @Database annotated abstract class with a singleton approach (for demonstration of the 3 data classes)** :-

```
@Database(
    entities = [ArticleTitleUniqueByPrimaryKey::class,ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkColumn::class,ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkAndTitleColumn::class],
    exportSchema = false,
    version = 1
)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database_db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- of course for an actual solution this is over the top as you would only have on such data class.

**Finally some activity code to demonstrate** :-

```
const val TAG = "DBINFO"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        val a1 = ArticleTitleUniqueByPrimaryKey(title = "Article 1", "www.link.article1",System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
        val aa1 = ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkColumn(title = a1.title, link = a1.link, publishDateTime = a1.publishDateTime)
        val aaa1 = ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkAndTitleColumn(link = a1.link, title = aa1.title, publishDateTime = a1.publishDateTime)

        insertWithLogging(a1)
        insertWithLogging(aa1)
        insertWithLogging(aaa1)

        /* Should all be rejected as Unique */
        insertWithLogging(a1)
        insertWithLogging(aa1)
        insertWithLogging(aaa1)

        val b1 = ArticleTitleUniqueByPrimaryKey(title = "Article 2", link = a1.link, publishDateTime = a1.publishDateTime)
        /* Title (Primary Key) is different so inserted OK */
        insertWithLogging(b1)
        /* Link is same as a1 Link so not inserted */
        insertWithLogging(ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkColumn(title = b1.title, link = b1.link, publishDateTime = b1.publishDateTime))
        /* Although Link is the same, the title is different to aaa1 then inserted */
        insertWithLogging(ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkAndTitleColumn(title = b1.title, link = b1.link, publishDateTime = b1.publishDateTime))

    }

    fun insertWithLogging(article: ArticleTitleUniqueByPrimaryKey) {
        val rowid = dao.insert(article)
        var result = "OK"
        if (rowid < 1) {
            result = "NO"
        }
        Log.d(TAG+"AUBPK","Result = INSERTED = $result Title is ${article.title} Link is ${article.link} ....")
    }
    fun insertWithLogging(article: ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkColumn) {
        val rowid = dao.insert(article)
        var result = "OK"
        if (rowid < 1) {
            result = "NO"
        }
        Log.d(TAG+"AUBLC","Result = INSERTED = $result Title is ${article.title} Link is ${article.link} ....")
    }
    fun insertWithLogging(article: ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkAndTitleColumn) {
        val rowid = dao.insert(article)
        var result = "OK"
        if (rowid < 1) {
            result = "NO"
        }
        Log.d(TAG+"AUB2","Result = INSERTED = $result Title is ${article.title} Link is ${article.link} ....")
    }
}
```

**Result**

When run *(note that the demo is intended to just be run the once)* then the log, as expected, includes:-

```
2022-12-14 07:56:06.876 D/DBINFOAUBPK: Result = INSERTED = OK Title is Article 1 Link is www.link.article1 ....
2022-12-14 07:56:06.878 D/DBINFOAUBLC: Result = INSERTED = OK Title is Article 1 Link is www.link.article1 ....
2022-12-14 07:56:06.894 D/DBINFOAUB2: Result = INSERTED = OK Title is Article 1 Link is www.link.article1 ....


2022-12-14 07:56:06.898 D/DBINFOAUBPK: Result = INSERTED = NO Title is Article 1 Link is www.link.article1 ....
2022-12-14 07:56:06.899 D/DBINFOAUBLC: Result = INSERTED = NO Title is Article 1 Link is www.link.article1 ....
2022-12-14 07:56:06.902 D/DBINFOAUB2: Result = INSERTED = NO Title is Article 1 Link is www.link.article1 ....


2022-12-14 07:56:06.905 D/DBINFOAUBPK: Result = INSERTED = OK Title is Article 2 Link is www.link.article1 ....
2022-12-14 07:56:06.910 D/DBINFOAUBLC: Result = INSERTED = NO Title is Article 2 Link is www.link.article1 ....
2022-12-14 07:56:06.912 D/DBINFOAUB2: Result = INSERTED = OK Title is Article 2 Link is www.link.article1 ....
```

- The first set of 3 results in all 3 rows being inserted (noting that they are 3 entirely separate tables i.e. the UNIQUEness is at the table level)
- The second set, a repitition of the first set are all NOT INSERTED due to captured and handled (IGNOREd) UNIQUE constraint conflict.
- The third set where the title is changed but the link is the same results in

  - the first row being inserted as the title (the primary key) is different.
  - the second, when the link column is the UNIQUE column is not inserted as the link is the same as the corresponding aa1 in the second table
  - the third is inserted as the combination of the title and the link is different as the title is different.

**App Inspection**

The 3 tables after running the above, via App Inspection (viewing the database via Android Studio) are:-

[image]

- As expected 2 rows as the uniqueness is on the **title** column/field and they differ.
  [image]
- Here the **id** column is an alias of the special **rowid** column and is the PRIMARY KEY. But as can be seen, due to the UNIQUE index on the **link** columnd/field that only 1 row exists as the 2nd attempt was IGNOREd as it had the the same value for the link column/field.
  [image]
- both rows, as the uniqueness is on **BOTH** the title and the link columns/fields combined (NOT just the title NOT just the link)

If you wanted neither the title or the link to ever be duplicated then you could have a UNIQUE index on both e.g.

```
@Entity(
    /* Unique on either the link or the title */
    indices = [
        Index(
            value = ["link"], unique = true
        ),
        Index(
            value = ["title"], unique = true
        )
    ]
)
data class ArticleTitleUniqueByLinkORTitleColumn(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long?=null, /* will be an alias of the rowid */
    var title: String,
    var link: String,
    var publishDateTime: Long
)
```